# Regex in Node.JS produces an unexpected match

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, validation, mobile

**here's my regex in Node:**

`/(0|\+98)?9[0|1|2|3|4|9][0-9]{8}$/g`

**here's my matching criteria in logical terms:**

`phoneNumber = ABCD where:
  A: country code (+98) || leading 0
  B: must be a 9
  C: must be a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 9
  D: eight digits from [0-9]`

**Here's the problem**

When I test a number which has a C component equal to 9, a strange thing happens, for example:

09**9**012345678 qualifies as a valid number when it shouldn't (**STRANGE**)

09**9**0123456 shouldn't qualify as a valid number and it doesn't (LOGICAL)

09**9**01234567 should qualify as a valid number and it does (LOGICAL)

09**9**01234567{..} do not qualify as valid and they shouldn't. (LOGICAL)

**I've tested this using Node.JS v7.2.0 and v6.10.3 on macOS 10.12.4
and on Ubuntu 16.04.2**

**Every other test yields correct results:**

090x.., 091x.., 092x.., 093x.., 094x.. --> MATCH (CORRECT)

+9891x.. --> MATCH (CORRECT)

095x.., 08xx.., --> NO MATCH (CORRECT)

091212345678 --> NO MATCH (CORRECT)

0912123456 --> NO MATCH (CORRECT)

etc ...

I suspect the strange behavior has to do with two 9's repeating; I played around with my regex for a couple of hours and finally gave up. Hoping someone could see the problem with my regex or point out a possible bug in Node's regex...

**Here are some variations that I've tried without any luck**

`/(0|\+98)?(9[0|1|2|3|4] | 99)[0-9]{8}$/g`

`/(0|\+98)?(9[0|1|2|3|4|9])\d{8}$/g`

`/(0|\+98)?(90|91|92|93|94|99)[0-9]{8}$/g`

`/(0|\+98)?9(?=[0|1|2|3|4|9])[0|1|2|3|4|9][0-9]{8}$/g`

**SOLUTION**

By the time I got the above writing finished and had a few more go's at it, realized I mistyped a question mark and my eyes could not see it even though I was staring at it the whole time with my eyes wide shut!

In conclusion:

Instead of this with an extra '?' before 9[0|1|2.. ,

> `/(0|\+98)?9[0|1|2|3|4|9][0-9]{8}$/g`

The solution is the following:

> `/(0|\+98)9[0|1|2|3|4|9][0-9]{8}$/g`

hope this helps out with a similar problem or 
gives you a working regex for **Iran mobile numbers**.

Just remember to trim the text if you are capturing it in an input field, and replace "-", " ", "(", ")" with "" before testing it with the regex.
so that 0912 123 4567, 0912-123-4567 and (0912)123-4567 don't bug you.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to help future readers.

Comment: Why use a global modifier if you anchor the match at the end of string? Also, if you need to match the whole string, add `^` at the beginning. You should also remove pipe symbols as they are treated as literal pipe symbols inside a character class. You may also just use a range inside a character class. Use `/^(0|\+98)9[0-49][0-9]{8}$/`.

Comment: Please post your answer and mark it as solved. that way no one needs to waste its time on a problem you already solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why use a global modifier if you anchor the match at the end of string? Also, if you need to match the whole string, add ^ at the beginning. You should also remove pipe symbols as they are treated as literal pipe symbols inside a character class. You may also just use a range inside a character class. Use `/^(0|\+98)9[0-49][0-9]{8}$/.` – Wiktor Stribiżew

Thanks Wiktor!